# trying to create a new column that observation responds to criteria within 2 separate columns and determines output

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a column with if else function. 
I Have a large data-set. I only need one of the columns to specify the if else function but i have multiple observations within the column which will be what the if else function is based on. I have taken the necessary observations from within the column. the original column is called lg$name. it is roughly set up like this

```
names <- c("UK STERLING", "US DOLLARS" ,"STH AFRICAN RAND")
cash <- c("GBP", "USD", "ZDA")
id <- c(1 ,2 ,3)
df <- data.frame(names,cash,id)
#new column 
df$type <- ifelse("UK Sterling", "cur" "not cur")
df$type <- ifelse("US DOLLARS", "cur", not cur")
#so on and so forth...
```

string contains the observations within the original data-set lg which will need to be used to determine output in new column. without having to run the multiple codes which will be inefficient in regards to data usage. I'm using data table package to do this.

```
 string <- ("AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR","BRAZILIAN REAL","CANADIAN DOLLAR","CHINESE 
        YUAN","COLOMBIAN PESO","DANISH KRONER",
        "EURO, , HONG KONG DOLLAR", "HUNGARIAN FORINT", "INDIAN RUPEE", 
       "INDONESIAN RUPIAH",
        "JAPANESE YEN", "KOREA (SOUTH) WON", "MEXICAN PESO","MALAYSIAN 
          RINGGIT",  
        "NORWEIGIAN KRONER", "NEW ZEALAND DOLLAR",  "PERUVIAN SOL", 
        "POLISH ZLOTY", "Russian Rouble (new)",
        "SINGAPORE DOLLAR", "STH AFRICAN RAND", 
        "SWEIDSH KRONER", "SWISS FRANC", "TAIWANESE DOLAR",
        "THAILAND BAHTS", "TURKISH LIRA","UK STERLING", "US DOLLAR")
```

Comment: can you give us an example what kind of output you are looking for? thanks

Comment: Hi, i edited the question which should be more helpful for you.  let me know what you think. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` :

```
df$type <- c('not cur', 'cur')[(df$names %in% string) + 1]
```

which is similar to :

```
df$type <- ifelse(df$names %in% string, 'cur', 'not cur')
```